# With top:0px;min-height:100% the div collapses even if the height of the parent is fixed

Tags: html, css

I tested it in blink, gecko and trident engine. The rendered height of the first div is zero.
If you add height (whatever value) the green child is visible and min-height is active.

```
<html><head>
<title>min-height and missing height</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 1024px; height: 768px;">
    <div id="outer" style="
min-width: 100%;min-height: 100%;
position:absolute;
left: 0px;top: 0px;
/* height:0; */
">
        <div id="inner" style="background-color:green;height:100%;width:100%"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The [Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights) says

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly
>   (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not
>   absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as '0' (for
>   'min-height') or 'none' (for 'max-height').

but as we have a fixed height of the containing block i don't think this part really describes the reason behind the collapse.

Has someone explanation (and a workaround) for that?
I can add a fake height:0 but this is quite expensive in my application as all dimensions can change at any time.

Comment: Would it work for you to add `position: absolute` to the nested `div` also? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/y7fsbkjy/1/

Comment: absolute is no option for me. 8-/

Answer (score 1):

> ...the div collapses even if the height of the parent is fixed

Well no, in this case the height of the parent is **not fixed**, the `body` has fixed height, but it's not the parent element of the inner div (it's the 'grand-parent').

Furthermore, the inner div isn't absolutely positioned - so - like the spec says: the calculated height for the inner div will be 0.

A simple workaround could be to add `position:absolute` to the inner div.

```css
body {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
}
.outer {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* height:0; */
}
.inner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute; /* <-- added this */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the parent is this element: <body style="width: 1024px; height: 768px;">

Comment: @Holger no, the parent of the inner div is `<div style="
min-width: 100%;min-height: 100%;
position:absolute;
left: 0px;top: 0px;
/* height:0; */
">` - and it **doesn't** set height explicitly

Comment: Oh, i begin to understand. The devtools says the outer div is full height. But the inner div height:100% does not look at the calculated height of the parent. Only if there is a dummy height.